# WebApp authentication with Kerberos with JWT as session management... does it make sense?

Tags: authentication, web, session, kerberos

I have to setup a webapp with some kind of session management and an authentication with Kerberos and I am a little bit lost... I just wanted to know from you pros if this approach makes sense at all or not. From my understanding it would be okay if the whole Kerberos authentication would just happen between the server part of the website (web application/web backend) and a kerberos instance and the session management would happen between the web frontend and the web backend. Language for the web app would be python. I saw there are Kerberos- and JWT-packages for it.

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me, I am doing the same thing, but in a micro-services setup : one component receives the credentials, ask Kerberos to validate them, and return a JWT. Then the user can pass its JWT to all the other services, which is simpler to do. Go for it !

Answer (score 0):

Quite long ago, but I just stumbled across here - from architecture perspective it depends as always on the requirements - you can do it, but it looks more like a hack and if you only have one Service JWT might be overkill. If you just try something out its fine. Remember to verify the JWT in your "webapp" again once it's in your mainservice If you are in an enterprise environment then I would recommend using keycloak instead of your "webapp" it can be configured such that it uses ldap as a User federation and then issue JWT to your frontend where it can be handled accordingly and then sent to your mainservice and there it can be verifed against keycloak again.